# Hover on text to show a tag title

Tags: jquery

```
<a href="#" id="magic"
 title="This is my sample.">
 Hover over this text</a>
<script>

    $('#magic').hover(function () { $(this).show('title') } );


</script>
```

Im trying to show the title in my a tag next to the a tag when the users hovers on the text

Answer (score 0):

Use this code that just works with HTML/CSS

```
<a href="#" id='myA' title='this is title'> this is text</a>
```

With this style:

```
#myA:hover:after{
    content:attr(title);
    color:red
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/72wd9eps/)